# uwsgi configuration with Nginx, with python scripts as cgi - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, python, cgi, uwsgi

This is my .ini file to run the uwsgi "pyApp.py"

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = cgi
socket = 127.0.0.1:9010
cgi = /=/usr/share/test/
cgi-allowed-ext = .py
cgi-helper = .py=python
```

i have a file "firstapp.py" at location /usr/share/test/firstapp.py Its contents are

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html><body><h1>It works! Cool!!</h1></body></html>"
```

I am running the instance of uwsgi with the command

```
uwsgi --http :9011 --http-modifier1 9 --ini pyApp.ini --master
```

I have configured several vhosts using nginx. and one of them must point to directory /usr/share/test/ when there is url having "/cgi-bin/" in it.

The nginx config is - [also the only default one among the others]

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /var/www/pythonsite.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name pythonsite.com www.pythonsite.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /cgi-bin {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_modifier1 9;
                uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9010;
        }
}
```

But when i try to access the "cgi" script from the browser via the url

```
http://pythonsite.com/cgi-bin/firstapp.py
```

The default URL "pythonsite.com" seems to be working fine but the above URl with "cgi-bin" in it seems to be missing something. I get "502 Bad Gateway". What am i missing. In order to use the python scripts this way?

**EDIT:**

Also, every time i request the URL http://pythonsite.com/cgi-bin/firstapp.py" in the browser, there is a log on the uwsgi server instance saying

```
-- unavailable modifier requested: 9 --
```

**EDIT 2:**

on the uwsgi logs i get "invalid request block size: 21573 (max 4096)...skip" for 127.0..0.1:9010 and connection was reset on the browser page

and for "127.0.0.1:9011/"; i get "internal Server Error" message on the browser. and uwsgi logs as `"--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---"`

What can be going wrong?  :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the CGI plugin installed ?

[Running CGI scripts on uWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/CGI.html)

With the same configuration I can reproduce the error, but after installing the CGI plugin and run  using the new binary in /tmp/uwsgi it works:

```
curl http://uwsgi.it/install | bash -s cgi /tmp/uwsgi
```

Comment: Thankyou for pointing that out. Is "uwsgi-plugin-cgi" the package i need to install. Like `"apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-cgi"`?

Comment: Thank you my friend. Thats what i had missed. Thank you very much !!!! :]  [ignore my previous comment]